# How do you increase humidity with HRV system?

Tags: hvac, furnace, humidity

I’m wondering how to increase the humidity in my home. I have a venmar constructo HRV system and have looked at the manual and many videos and can’t find the answer. I’d like my humidity to be 35% for winter as we have triple pane windows. It seems that no matter where I set the dial, it never gets higher than 32% and seems to fluctuate between 30-32% regardless of the setting. Does this mean that my newer 2015 system is broken already or is something else going on? I’ve had the dial set between -4F to 23F and even higher and the actual humidity doesn’t seem to change. Right now the outdoor temp is around 23F (-5C) so I’m worried that it’s only going to become dryer as it gets colder. Any thoughts/ideas to help me please?

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. The Venmar is an air-to-air exchanger; do you have a humidifier?

Comment: I thought it was a heat recovery system , unless it has an internal humidifier I agree with Daniel. If it has a humidifier it is probably plugged up they require more maintenance than most folks realize.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actively increase humidity with an HRV, at least during the cold months. The dial control allows you to run the unit as needed to *reduce* humidity by exchanging more moist indoor air with dry outdoor air. If you'd like to raise humidity you need to actually introduce moisture into your home.

A standalone humidifier in an appropriate location has done well for me in the past if you wish to avoid the expense of a whole-house unit. Place it where the air movement won't create discomfort and where the HVAC system will help circulate and distribute moisture.

By the way, you should not settle on a fixed RH for the entire winter season. You want to vary it depending on the outdoor temperature to avoid excessive moisture buildup and to prevent discomfort. 35% is quite low if it's 50 degrees F. outside, and may be high if it's -30F.

> - Outdoor temperature over 50˚F, indoor humidity levels shouldn’t exceed 50%
> - Outdoor temperature over 20˚F, indoor humidity levels shouldn’t exceed 40%
> - Outdoor temperature between 10˚F and 20˚F, indoor humidity levels shouldn’t exceed 35%
> - Outdoor temperature between 0˚F and 10˚F, indoor humidity levels shouldn’t exceed 30%
> - Outdoor temperature between -10˚F and 0˚F, indoor humidity levels shouldn’t exceed 25%
> - Outdoor temperature between -20˚F and -10˚F, indoor humidity levels shouldn’t exceed 20%
> - Outdoor temperature at -20˚F or lower, indoor humidity levels shouldn’t exceed 15%
>
> <sub>[source](https://www.hvac.com/faq/recommended-humidity-level-home/)</sub>

Comment: I like portables for several reasons but the first is easier to clean and a malfunction won't flood the duct work if central air/ heat. I did not realize at the much colder levels the humidity needed to be lowered that much but where I am it rarely gets in to the nasty minus territory. +

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! I’ll invest in a portable humidifier!

Comment: You're welcome. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to be sure you know what's expected of you when you ask a question.